# Gcloud components update -> can't find import

Tags: github, jwt, gcloud, jwt-go

Our code base has been compiling just fine up until now.  Today, gcloud started pestering me with its update message again, so I ran a "gcloud components update" and it updated successfully.

However, now when I try to deploy our project using "`gcloud preview app deploy .`", I get the following error:

> can't find import: "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"

The line hasn't changed since it was properly deploying before the update.  I've already tried a "`go get -u github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`", which worked (though I'm not sure if local packages affect the deployment anyway).  Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Ran a gcloud components restore and it started working again, so it seems to be an issue with the latest components release.  Red alert canceled.

Comment: Are you using vm:true in your app.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently gcloud is in a state of transition for the go tools. It does work with appcfgy.py under the latest (Cloud SDK 0.9.57).

/path/to/your/google-cloud-sdk/bin/appcfg.py update --oauth2 <my_module>/app.yaml -A <application id> -V <version>