# "goapp build" works, but "appcfg.py update" just "can't find import"...?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

After updating the Google App Engine SDK last night...
Both `go env` and `goapp env` have the correct GOPATH and GOROOT, `go build` and `goapp build` both work, but `appcfg.py update ...` returns that every third-party package is missing.

Even if I run `goapp get ...` or `go get ...` again for each package, it makes no difference since they're already in the GOPATH anyway. That alone should be confirmed by the fact that **both commands** build the project.

What could be wrong? :(

---

**EDIT:** It produces different errors each time I run `appcfg.py update .` ...

> main.go:4: can't find import: "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
>   github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding/default_validator.go:7: can't find
>   import: "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8"
>   github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:17: can't find import:
>   "github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding"

... Ran `goapp get ...` on all of these, even though they're already there.

> main.go:4: can't find import: "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
>   github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/gzip/gzip.go:9: can't find import:
>   "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" github.com/gin-gonic/gin/render/yaml.go:10:
>   can't find import: "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

... Repeat, run `goapp get ...` on all of these again.

> main.go:4: can't find import: "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
>   github.com/gin-gonic/gin/render/yaml.go:10: can't find import:
>   "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

Makes no sense. The libraries are already there. I can do `goapp build` and it works, but **I can't deploy.**

All of this is inside the "--- begin server output ---" and "--- end server output ---" wrappings... is this a server-side issue?

Comment: Is the path to go_appengine/appcfg.py in your GOPATH ? If you can run appcfg.py using its whole path w/o errors then it's probably not in GOPATH or GOROOT.

Comment: No, it's not. Should it be? Adding it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Also, I just spun up a Compute Engine instance and have the same exact problem there... even on a fresh install.

Comment: Added console output above.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `goapp deploy` instead of appcfg.py for golang deployments.  Does that work?

Comment: @JustinBeckwith No, same thing. :(

Comment: It's basically the exact same scenario as this, but I can't call `gcloud restore`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685544/gcloud-components-update-cant-find-import

Comment: Solution posted below. Thanks @JustinBeckwith for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/rVHZXlSfC7E ... As noted here by another user, this is a temporary issue with Google App Engine.

It can be solved by commenting out the `main()` method in the main package of your project. Normally, `init()` is used, so this does not currently cause any other issue except a minor inconvenience when deploying to other platforms simultaneously or building locally for non-App Engine execution.

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue with the App Engine SDK for Go caught during rollout and addressed.  It was tracker in public [Issue 13230](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13230).  This should no longer be in effect.

One important note that, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/quickstart#hello_world_code_review), one should not implement a `main()` function in a Go GAE application as the behavior is [unspecified](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13230#c6).

Should anyone still be encountering this issue, please file a new defect report on the [App Engine public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) linking back to [Issue 13230](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13230) for context.